# Where is my error in the consideration on entropy production?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Lets say we have a heat exchange unit which takes heat from a hot reservoir (a boiler) and dispenses heat to a radiator. I wonder about entropy balance:
[image]

Heat amount Q flows through from left to right.
What about entropy?

$S_1 = Q/T_1$ is taken from the left

$S_2 = Q/T_2$ is given to the right

So there is a net entropy "production" of $Q/T_2-Q/T_1$. Since $T_2 < T_1$ this yields a positive net entropy balance for the whole system.

But since entropy increases for the whole system, the process as a whole must be irreversible (which is not surprising).

But, for irreversible processes I learned that

$\delta Q < T dS$

So something is inconsistent with my entropy balance, because I assumed $\delta Q= TdS$ on the interfaces, which is the statement for reversible processes.

What is wrong with my consideration and what is the right way to make a statement about entropy balance for that example?

EDIT: This is neither a homework nor a check-my-work question and I have no idea, why people who closed the topic for exactly that reason came to such conclusion at all.

Comment: You are taking heat from a finite reservoir and are putting heat into another but the temperatures stay the same? I don't think that's exactly what would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is *reversible* then in the first step the engine at temperature $T_1$ absorbs entropy $S_1$ at temperature $T_1$ and then by a reversible adiabatic process it drops its temperature to $T_2$ during which it performs $W_{12}=(T_1-T_2)S_1$ work at the end of which it expels $S_1$ entropy at temperature $T_2$. This being a reversible process it conserves *total* entropy: (1) isothermally absorbs $S_1$, (2) adiabatic (isentropic) work, no change in entropy, (3) isothermally expels entropy $S_1$.

If the engine is to operate in a cycle then at the lower temperature isothermal stage is followed by raising the engine's temperature by a reversible adiabatic (isentropic) work process back to $T_1$.

If you process at any instant is irreversible, then at that moment and stage the entropy there increases, and to complete *a* cycle more entropy will have to be expelled at the lower temperature $T_2$ than absorbed at $T_1$.

---

If the process produces no work, then it is either isothermal or by necessity it must be irreversible and that is because during the process you have cooled all the entropy in the engine including the one you have just absorbed. Since your question explicitly assumes a higher temperature at which entropy is absorbed and a lower temperature at which it is expelled without work that can only happen via conduction and that process actually does increase the entropy inside the engine by exactly the amount that is not expelled at the lower temperature.

Whether you can say that $\delta Q =TdS$ depends on what you mean by $\delta Q$ and $dS$. If the reservoir is transferring $\delta Q$ thermal energy at temperature $T$ then $dS$ is the amount of entropy by which the reservoir's entropy decreases and if the engine is also at $T$ then $dS$ is the amount the engine receives. If the process is also reversible then $dS$ is also the amount by which the engine's own internal entropy increases, if the process is irreversible then $dS$ is just one part of the total increase. See [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742232/why-isnt-heat-conduction-considered-a-form-of-work/742245#742245).

Comment: I was thinking not in terms of a machine but just of a boiler (left) and an attached radiator which warms something (right). There is no work done in a cycle. My whole process is irreversible of course. Is it valid  to say that dS = dQ/T for irreversible processes? I want just to calculate the net entropy production, when a small amount of heat passes from left to the right.

Comment: see my addition above.

Comment: I will continue tomorrow. Thanks for your answer, but I cannot think clearly anymore. I ask tomorrow again after reading and anticipating your answer.

Comment: In the meanwhile it became clear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your system to be made of two parts, one at $T_1=100$°C and one at $T_2=20$°C. When you write $\Delta S_1 = |Q|/T_1$ and $\Delta S_2 = -|Q|/T_2$ you are assuming that each part is in the thermal equilibrium, i.e., you are ignoring the temperature gradients inside each part. That's a common assumption. The irreversible aspect is in the *boundary* between the two systems, where the temperature drops from 100°C to 20°C.

In summary:

1. the system consists of two parts
2. each part is in internal equilibrium so that $Q = T \Delta S$ within the part
3. the parts are *not* in equilibrium with each other, hence we have entropy generation

Some textbooks describe this situation by stating that $dQ = T dS$ is valid as long as the process in *mechanically reversible*, implicitly assuming that the system is in thermal equilibrium, i.e it is characterized by uniform temperature.

Comment: I was assuming a system in the middle, where the left is at T1 and the right at T2, thereby ignoring any details in the inner, including a temperature gradient within the middle. Is it now wrong to say, that entropy transfer at the boundaries is dQ/T ?

Comment: In the standard analysis the system in the middle is squeezed into a boundary of zero width and zero mass that has no entropy of its own. If you want to consider it.you need to use additional approximations, for example, slice it into narrow bands each with each own temperature and treat each band as if in internal equilibrium. Moreover, there is no entropy transfer, only heat transfer. Entropy is an extensive property of state, to calculate total $\Delta S$ we add the entropy change of the parts. In the standard analysis the entropy of the middle part is  neglected.

Answer (score 1):

The entropy generation occurs along the through-length of the interfaces. This matches our understanding that entropy is generated whenever energy moves down a gradient. If you've found a paradox, it's probably because you idealized these interfaces as having a thickness of zero. Even so, you could consider the entropy production to correspond to that plane, as long as you sidestep the impossibility of a single point having two temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the orange and blue are ideal constant temperature reservoirs, for which $\Delta S_1=-Q/T_1$ and $\Delta S_2=Q/T_2$.  This is perfectly OK, because they are assumed to be essentially operating reversibly (internally).  So where is all the entropy being generated?  In the ideal operation you are indicating, all the entropy generation is assumed to be occurring within the  heat exchange tubing (yellow) which is conducting heat from orange to blue:   $$\Delta S_{yellow}=Q/T_1-Q/T_2+\sigma_{yellow}=0$$$\Delta S_{yellow}$ is assumed to be zero since it is assumed to be operating at steady state.  Therefore, $$\sigma_{yellow}=Q/T_2-Q/T_1>0$$In the real world, there will be thermal boundary layers in the orange reservoir and the blue reservoir, situated adjacent to the yellow conducting wall.  Entropy will be generated within these boundary layers as well.